# Why was this marked as unclear if they had said it was off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

I have a question about my Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange post: [Why are some families more into tradition than others, and use their surnames as a way to enforce them?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14176/why-are-some-families-more-into-tradition-than-others-and-use-their-surnames-as)

I asked a perfectly good question. Why do families use their surnames to enforce rules and traditions? How clearer could I get?
If this is not a family history question, is there not a sociology site? If not, is ther e a way to get one started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of us thought it was unclear, some of us thought it was off-topic (I happen to think it was both, but you can only pick a single reason to close). However, unless you work on it substantially to make the focus clear **and** on-topic, it is not about tracing the history of your family/genealogy, which is what this site is about.

There are a number of Stack Exchange sites that have a sociology tag where it **might** be on-topic (Google for "Stack Exchange Sociology") but you would have to read the guidance on each one to decide where it might best fit.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is problematic because it doesn't say how this information will be helpful to you in answering a research question for your genealogy and family history. From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

As the question is written, you are asking the community to evaluate the information that was given to you in a book which you've read, but you didn't cite. We have no information whatsoever about this alleged Beauchamp family, so any reason we might give would be pure speculation. Social rules, like laws, differ depending on time and place.  Without a time frame or a location, it isn't of any use in putting historical records in context, or helping you solve a problem.

You're also asking us to speculate on the actions that your own family might have taken:

> I come from the Garcia family. Would any of my parents or grandparents
>   say, I was a Garcia every time I did something they didn't approve of?

If **you** don't know whether or not **your own parents** criticized you or any of your siblings by saying "Garcias don't do that" then how are a bunch of strangers on the Internet supposed to know?

This might be an entertaining discussion topic on a forum, but open-ended discussions aren't on-topic for this site.

From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Also, an open-ended discussion that covers any time and place -- surname-based 'enforcement' around the world and through the ages -- also falls afoul of this guideline:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

In conclusion, if there are so many issues with a question that the community has multiple answers for why the question is not a good fit for our site, that's a strong indicator that it doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 3):

I think that there is also a case for your question ([Why are some families more into tradition than others, and use their surnames as a way to enforce them?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14176)) to be closed in its current state for the reason below:

> **primarily opinion-based**
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

As a new user of G&FH SE be sure to take its [Tour](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about its focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.